# GridSearchCV with SVM estimator AUC score not reproduced on SVM run

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I've run `GridSearchCV` to determine 'best parameters' for a linear SVM, and then passed these [in a dictionary along with non-tuned parameters] into a new SVM.

I've printed out the parameter dictionaries and confirmed that the output of the grid search feeds the parameters correctly into the new SVM (`sklearn.svm.SVC()`), and yet where the grid search achieved AUC of 0.89, on the same dataset I achieve just 0.5, and *"no predicted samples"*.

To confirm, I set the `param_grid` to a 1x1 grid (i.e. no searching, just running 5-fold cross-val using SVM estimator) and it still "does well" only to drop to 0.5 AUC score afterwards.

Can anyone please help diagnose this disparity?

---

(Note that this code has a reduced `logspace` parameter space, to reduce running time after I found the most performant values)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit, GridSearchCV

def SVMParamTune(model_class, X, y, params):
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    C_range = np.logspace(-2, -2, 1)
    gamma_range = np.logspace(3, 3, 1)
    param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
    # If the configuration contains other parameters, use these
    # These are the 'constants' to parameterising the SVM
    for param_name in params:
        if param_name not in param_grid.keys():
            pass
            # param_grid[param_name] = params[param_name]
    cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    # NB the SVC estimator provides a `score` method,
    # meaning GridSearchCV uses mean accuracy (from this estimator's score)
    grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=10, verbose=10)
    grid.fit(X, y)
    print("The best parameters are %s with an AUC score of %0.2f"
                  % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
    print(grid.best_params_)
    for param in params:
        if param in grid.best_params_.keys():
            params[param] = grid.best_params_[param]
    print(params)
    return params
```

This is run, I see a good result, yet the result doesn't make it out of the tuning process for reasons unknown.

```
m_params = SVMParamTune(m_class, X=data[0], y=data[1], params=m_params)
```

The class (`sklearn.svm.SVC`, stored in `m_class`) is then run with these updated parameters, and yet gives different results

```
model_run = m_class(**m_params)
```

Switching `StratifiedShuffleSplit` to `StratifiedKFold` to be consistent with the latter SVM run made negligible difference so cannot be the cause.

**Update** returning the model itself also gives the same changed AUC score - the model itself cannot be reproduced, on the same data...

Comment: Could you post a short but runnable piece of code?